# How to get rid of banding when drawing a gradient to a widget?

Tags: android, widget, gradient

I've seen a lot of similar questions which have been answered, stating how to remove banding in a window, but I've been unable to find anything to point me in the right direction with regards to a homescreen widget.

The app draws a gradientDrawable to a canvas, and then uses that as the background for the widget. In the main app Activity I've been able to use the following code to make it look much better:

```
Window window = getWindow();
window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

But is there a way to somehow achieve the same effect in the widget? I have tried using `gradientDrawable.setDither(true);`
but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

I'd appreciate any pointers, thanks